# Django rest framework unable to select item to post

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im trying to post from DRF dashboard, While I'm not finding dropdown so that i can select Title

[image]

The title for posting is not dropdown of title, which is required

model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    title=models.ForeignKey(Post)
    comments=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

Serializer.py

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(source="title.title", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('title','comments')


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id','title','description','pub_date')
```

How should I make drop-down of Title to select title

Any help on this is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the ["serializer relation"](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) section of the documentation.

You'll likely want to use a `SlugRelatedField` instead of the `CharField`.
Also note that your comments are marked as `read_only` on the code extract while it read/write on your screenshot.